# combine XML objects PHP

Tags: php, xml

It's pretty straightforward, I have an array with a number of nodes of the same structure available as Simple XML objects (extracted from different XML documents). What's the easiest way to add them to a single XML document, so I can output the combined XML? I've searched, but I can't find a good solution.

Edit: Array looks like this, how do I combine these objects in one single XML object?

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [no] => 23432423
                        [type] => Array
                    )

                [id] => 40043030
                [title] => Cars
                [cinemadate] => 2011-07-06
                [changedate] => 2011-07-27T10:19:00
                [year] => 2011
                [length] => 112
                [genres] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [genre] => animatie
                    )


[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [no] => 48050593
                        [type] => Array
                    )

                [id] => 1231676
                [title] => Arrietty
                [cinemadate] => 2011-07-06
                [changedate] => 2011-06-21T10:39:00
                [genres] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [genre] => animatie
                    )
```

Comment: How do you want to merge them? Does the second overwrites anything duplicated of the first?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear, I don't want to actually merge them. I want them both as nodes in a new XML object, so I can output them both in a single XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array and add the data to the existing simplexml object. You have not provided much information in your question how the array data looks like nor have you provided an example simplexml object / xml chunk, so there is not much more to say  specifically.